# Fijar la posición de un elemento al final

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente documento en el cual diseñe una especie de "Pestañas" para navegar, algo asi como las pestañas de cualquier navegador donde siempre hay un boton "+' para agregar una pestaña la cual se crea a la derecha de la que ya esta abierta y el boto "+" siempre queda al final no importa cuantas cree, mi codigo funciona de la siguiente manera:

Al darle click al boton "+" se crea una pestaña en el beforeend de un contenedor para asi dar la apariencia de que se genera a la derecha de la que ya esta creada, pero el boton "+" queda como la 2da opcion, mi pregunta es como puedo fijar el boton "+" para que quede siempre al beforeend del contenedor (quizas la respusta sea muy simple pero no he podido solucionarlo). gracias

```
<!-- page content -->
            <div class="right_col" role="main">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="x_panel">
                            <div class="x_title">
                                <h2 style="padding-top: 5px;"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-invoice-dollar"></i> Cotización</h2>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>                                
                            </div>
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link active" id="op1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#op1" role="tab" aria-controls="op1" aria-selected="true">Opcion 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" id="Agregar-op"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="op1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="op1-tab"> <br> <?php include('cotizacion_content.php') ?></div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- /page content -->
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $('#myTab li:first-child a').tab('show')
                })

                $('#Agregar-op').click(function(){
                    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-pane").length + 1;
                    console.log(divs);
                    var d1 = document.getElementById('myTab');
                    var d2 = document.getElementById('tab-content');
                    d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" id="op'+divs+'-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#op'+divs+'" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Opcion '+ divs+'</a> </li>');
                    d2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="tab-pane" id="op'+divs+'" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="op'+divs+'-tab"></div>');
                    
                })
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que en tu caso específico esto es lo que necesitas.

Modifica esta línea:

```javascript
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" id="op'+divs+'-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#op'+divs+'" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Opcion '+ divs+'</a> </li>');
```

por esta otra:

```javascript
this.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" id="op' + divs + '-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#op' + divs + '" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Opcion ' + divs + '</a> </li>');
```

Con ello estas invocando el método [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) justo sobre el elemento padre del enlace `+` (`this.parentElement`), que es un elemento `<li>`, incorporando al DOM el nuevo elemento `<li>` de la pestaña nueva en la posición que deseas.

Aquí te dejo un snippet de ejemplo con el resultado (y con algunas pocas modificaciones tan solo para ver si los tabs seguian funcionando a pesar de no modificar la siguiente linea):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myTab li:first-child a').tab('show')
})

$('#Agregar-op').click(function() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-pane").length + 1;
  console.log(divs);
  var d1 = document.getElementById('myTab');
  var d2 = document.getElementById('tab-content');
  this.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" id="op' + divs + '-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#op' + divs + '" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Opcion ' + divs + '</a> </li>');
  d2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="tab-pane" id="op' + divs + '" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="op' + divs + '-tab"><br> Pestaña ' + divs + '</div>');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- page content -->
<div class="right_col" role="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="x_panel">
        <div class="x_title">
          <h2 style="padding-top: 5px;"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-invoice-dollar"></i> Cotización</h2>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="op1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#op1" role="tab" aria-controls="op1" aria-selected="true">Opcion 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="Agregar-op">+<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="op1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="op1-tab"> <br> Pestaña 1</div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me sirvió, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo con el [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) que permite dibujar en el doom antes de un elemento especifico

```js
let num = 1;
// hacemos un listener para el evento click
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
   // del evento seleccionamos el target
   // quien inicio el envento en este caso #btn
   let self =e.target;
   // creamos un elemento span
   let newspan = document.createElement("span");
   // le asignamos texto
   let text = document.createTextNode(`n${num} `);
   // agregamos el texto al span
   newspan.appendChild(text);
   // de input buscamos su padre con parentNode
   // lo insertamos antes que input
   self.parentNode.insertBefore(newspan,self);
   // aumentamos es para el ejemplo
   num++;
})
```

```html
<div>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="+">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Crea una etiqueta vas con los atributos

```
.fixzed { 
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 10px;// para que no quede pegado por completo al fondo
 left: 10px // para separarlo un poco del borde de la apagina
}
```

Con esto el botón siempre quedará en pegado en el bot aún cuando realices scroll